# Can't search in the Spring Tool Suite 3 marketplace

Tags: sts, eclipse-marketplace

I am getting an error every time i try to search any plugin. I have tried with java 8 too but the result is the same:

```
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p/search/apachesolr_search/decompiler?client=org.eclipse.epp.mpc.core&client.version=1.7.5.v20190225-1757&os=win32&ws=win32&nl=es_ES&java.version=11.0.21&product=org.springsource.sts.ide&product.version=3.9.8.201903260800-RELEASE-e411&runtime.version=3.15.200.v20190301-1641&platform.version=4.11.0.v20190307-0500
HttpComponents connection error response code 500.
```

I haven't done any change and my network connection is the same without any vpn. I have tried to change Network Connections to Direct and Manual.

Comment: Today a new version of EPP Marketplace Client has been released https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/archive/simrel/epp-mpc.aggrcon/index.html. I have tried to update with this link http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/drops/1.10.3/v20240221-1216 but i can't install it due to problems with its dependencies